# Multi-tabla con Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Chicos necesito un ejemplo de como hacer una multitabla en criteria, por más que busco no encuentro, os dejo una query como ejemplo, solo busco un ejemplo no una solucion a mi query, sino que la query es de esa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM
PER_TIPO_REL_SERV TR, PER_DATOS_LISTIN DL WHERE  TR.CTIPO_REL_SERV=DL.TIPO_REL_SERV
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un join en JPA Criteria puedes ver este link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990141/how-to-make-a-criteriabuilder-join-with-a-custom-on-condition) tambien te te mando el ejemplo con tu query pero solo asegurate de tener bien mapeadas las relaciones de las tablas, te dejo el codigo de como podria quedar el query con criteriaBuilder

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
ArrayList<Predicate> lstPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
CriteriaQuery<PerTipoRelServ> query = cb.createQuery(PerTipoRelServ.class);
Root<PerTipoRelServ> tipo = query.from(PerTipoRelServ.class);
Join<PerTipoRelServ, PerDatosListin> datos = tipo.join("cTipoRelServ");
Predicate pDatos = cb.equal(datos.<Integer>get("tipoRelServ"), cTipoRelServ);
lstPredicates.add(pDatos);
query.where(cb.and(lstPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[lstPredicates.size()])));
List<PerTipoRelServ> lstTipo = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Raul, pero porqué un "JOIN"? yo solo quiero hacer la comparación de dos tablas, o e que es la única manera? saludos

Comment: por ahora tengo esto que me devuelve todo:
' @Override
 public List<PerTipoRelServ> findAll() {

  HibernateTemplate ht = getHibernateTemplate();

  DetachedCriteria dc =   DetachedCriteria.forClass(PerTipoRelServ.class);
  return castList(PerTipoRelServ.class, ht.findByCriteria(dc));
 }'

Comment: en critery si es la unica opcion si usar jpa entonces si se podria hacelo sin un join